# How do I create an equation for an alternating sequence of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm working on a program that takes an input (`n`) and outputs a number. The output is based on a two step alternating sequence, +1 and +3 - that is one step goes up 1, second step goes up 3, third step goes up 1 and so on. The set is $\{1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, ...\}$

Is it possible to create an equation based on that? I'm not very knowledgeable of calculus symbols or terms so if you could keep it as simple as possible for a programmer that would be great.

Comment: Observe that if you add $+1$ to each of the odd numbers, you simply get the sequence $2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, \ldots$  That suggests that you can just start with the even numbers, and then do (what?) in order to obtain the desired sequence.

Comment: You have several formulas for this sequence in http://oeis.org/A042948

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start counting the terms at $1$, you have $$f(n)=2n-(n \bmod 2)$$

Answer (score 2):

$f(n) = \frac{1}{2} \left(4 n+(-1)^n-1\right)$

[image]

But if your goal is to *code* this function (as it seems), well that is particularly easy.  In *Mathematica*:

```
f[1] = 1;
f[n_] := If[EvenQ[n], f[n - 1] + 3, f[n - 1] + 1]
```

or

```
f[n_]:= Floor[ 4/3 Floor[3 n/2]]
```

or

```
f[n_]:= 2 n - Mod[n,2]
```

or

```
f[n_]:= 2n + (−1)^n/2 − 1/2
```

or

```
f[1] = 1;
f[2] = 4;
f[3] = 5;
f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2] - f[n - 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something easy to code I found on OEIS:

$$
f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{4}{3}\left\lfloor\frac{3n}{2}\right\rfloor\right\rfloor
$$